# OpenGL ES iPhone switching from IB to initWithFrame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

Hey guys, I am writing a custom view for doing OpenGLES rendering. I got it working when I had a view in interface builder and set the class to my rendering view, but now I switched to creating the view with initWithFrame. (Note I can set the background color of the view and see it I just can't render anything in OpenGL not even the clear color) Everything seems to be getting called and the layer class seems ok too it just for some reason does not work outside of directly creating it with InterfaceBuilder. Any Ideas?

I have this setup code:

```
+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) 
    {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self setupView];
    }   
    return self;
}

- (void)setupView
{
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error could not set context");
        [self release];
    }

    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(renderView:)];
    _displayLink.paused = YES;
    _displayLink.frameInterval = FPS;

    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];

    [self setup];
}
```

And then some layout code.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
    [self destroyBuffers];
    if (![self createBuffers]){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create framebuffer!");
    }

    [self resumeRendering];
}
```

And some rendering code:

```
- (void)renderView:(CADisplayLink*)sender
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _viewFrameBuffer);

        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     



        GLenum attachments[] = {GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
        glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, 2, attachments);


        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _viewRenderBuffer);


    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

}
```

I can't figure out why nothing is rendering as all the same things are getting called. If anyone can help me out that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I maybe speculating too much here but switching from IB to initWithFrame has a step omitted, that is loadView in your viewController, which is where you would instantiate your custom view class instead of a standard view class.

Comment: Uh yeah I did that I make it with initWithFrame and add it as a subview. Like I said I can see the view if I set the background color I just can't do any opengl rendering not even the clear color